# Embedding Opera in Cocoa

Tags: cocoa, embed, opera

So, I'm writing a Cocoa application that needs to be able to display web content using Opera's rendering engine. This is for a feature, not because I'm an Opera fanboi (I'm not). All I've been able to find on the subject is this [press release about Adobe's use of the Opera engine](http://www.opera.com/pressreleases/en/2003/09/30/).

Has anyone done this? What's the API like? Are they going to want royalties, payments, an NDA, etc?

Edited to add: This is for a cross-engine web debugging tool. I'm going to be using this alongside WebKit.

Comment: Can you provide an explanation why the obvious solution (embed Webkit) won't work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adobe has gone to Opera and licensed their software for some (exorbitant?) amount of money. What that probably means is Adobe has access to the library and SDK documentation so they can embed it in their applications. Opera doesn't give its engine away for free as in beer or freedom. It appears there are several B2B opportunities and I'm sure for the right amount of money you can get access to it. More information can be found out at http://www.opera.com/b2b/.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you need to embed the Opera engine, instead of the platform-standard rendering engine?

"Consistency between platforms" — the typical argument I hear for something like this — is far better achieved by carefully managing your content, providing appropriate style sheets, and so on.

You'll be much better off from a user and platform-integration perspective using WebKit in your application on Mac OS X and using whatever the IE control is called on Windows.

Comment: Because I'm writing a cross-engine debugger tool and it'd be nice to support the Opera engine too.